# What tool do programmer teams use to communicate about coding?

Tags: github

Its the first time that I'm engaged in a project that I'm coding not by myself but together with another guy from a remote location. In order to make it possible, we set-up a project on a GitHub. Now I wonder what tools do programmer teams use in such cases like when I'm reviewing new changes and some portion of code is unclear/erroneous and I want to start conversation about it. I imagine this should be something like microforum, with email notifications about new posts. Is it something that is integrated into GitHub functionality or should I look for some separate tool?

Comment: Teams now at days tend to use Slack

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try